# BizTalk 2006 Tutorial 1: EDI-to-XML Document Translation

Tags: biztalk, edi, biztalk-2006

I cannot find the translated file after running the solution in BizTalk 2006 Tutorial Lesson 3: Run the EDI-to-XML Solution.

It should be placed in the c:\Program Files\Microsoft BizTalk Server 2006 \EDI\Adapter\Getting Started with EDI\Northwind\In folder.

The Base EDI adapter picks up the file in c:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Microsoft\BizTalk Server 2006 \EDI\Subsystem\Documents\PickupEDI folder, but I cannot find the translated file in the X-12 4010 850 document format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not immediately familiar with the tutorial you mention, but below are steps to find where any document has gone to in BizTalk.

First two places to check are in the event viewer and in the BizTalk Server Administration Console.

Check you have no errors in the event viewer.

In the admin console, click on the BizTalk Group in the left hand window and you should see two columns in the right hand pane, *Work in Progress* and *Suspended Items*. Click on *Running service instances* and *Suspended service instances*. Check that you message is not delayed for any reason (a Send Port being turned off perhaps).

Next, from *Start* -> *All Programs* -> *Microsoft BizTalk Server 2006* select the *Health and Activity Tracking* (HAT) tool.

In HAT, select Queries -> Most recent 100 service instances. Find the pipeline that will have wrote out your file, right click the service instance and select Message Flow. In the message flow view you should see in the URL the disk location where your file was written to.

(You can also look in the admin console to check where the send port is pointing)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your suggestion regarding how to troubleshoot an issue of BizTalk Server from generic point of view. It did help. I have resolved this problem by reading error logs.

Here is the error:

Access denied. The client user must be a member of one of the following accounts to perform this function.
 SSO Administrators: SSO Administrators
 SSO Affiliate Administrators: SSO Affiliate Administrators
 Application Administrators: BizTalk Server Administrators
 Application Users: BizTalk Application Users

It works now after adding a service account to "SSO Administrators" and restart all BizTalk related services.